# sql query with row comparing in where class

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql, firebird

I have two tables, `Customers` and `Products`. A customer can have more than one product.

I am trying to retrieve customers that do not have a specific product.

For example, 10 customers bought products `A` and `B`, another 10 customers bought `A`, `B`, and `C`. How can I retrieve those customers that do not have the `C` product?

Comment: You'll need to provide your table structure. We're not psychic!

Comment: Presumably there are at least *three* tables here: `customers` (aka clients) who can buy things, `products` that can be bought, and a third table e.g. `purchases` showing which customers bought which products.  Am I right?

Comment: Customers
id
name
phone
address

Products
id
name
price
customer_id

Comment: hi tony your right i forgot to mention there is a purchases table as well sorry.

Comment: @user1010861 What you should really do is to update your question with the DB structure...

Comment: And add the homework tag (if it is homework). I assume you don't need the answer in all those RDBMS, too.

Comment: Good call, @ypercube. To OP: Please remove all RDBMS specific tags and leave only your actual RDBMS tag.

Comment: @user1010861: I tried to clear up your post a bit. Please review my edit in case I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

For your current DB structure, this is what you are looking for:

```
select c.id, c.name, c.phone, c.address 
from Customers c
where not exists (select * from products p 
                  where p.customer_id = c.id and p.id = 'c')
```

However, you should consider creating a third table to store the individual purchases.

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
FROM customer c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from products p 
                  WHERE p.customer_id = c.id)
```

You should really (as suggested already by @Tony andrews and @Adrian) have a third table to store details of which customers bought which product.

Somthing like:

```
**Customer**
Id
Name
Address
Phone

**Product**
Id
Name
Price

**Customer_Product**
customer_id
product_id
```

This means you're removing redundancy from your product table. Consider what you'd need to do if a product name changed slightly - instead of updating multiple rows (as you'd have to do now), you'd only have to update 1 row, and you wouldn't need to touch your transaction history at all..

Comment: hi guys this how it looks like i have 3 tables as following customers, products, purchases and lets put this way i have 3 10 products i wanna pull all the records from database where clients dont have a specific product for instance `select c.name, c.status, c.contact_number from purchases p join clients c on p.cid = c.id where not exists (product_a)` 
thanks